# curl to PowerShell command

Tags: powershell, curl

Below is a curl script that gives the out in the json format (for details of snapshots):

```
curl -k -s -u superadmin:password-X GET https://127.0.0.1/snapshots -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

I'm new to Powershell. I'm not sure which one to use. `Invoke-RestMethod` or `Invoke-WebRequest`.

I executed the below command:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://127.0.0.1/snapshots' -Method GET -Credential $cred
```

And I get the below error:

> Invoke-WebRequest : Unable to connect to the remote server At line:2
> char:1  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://127.0.0.1/snapshots' -Method
> GET - ... CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation:
> (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest],
> WebException FullyQualifiedErrorId :
> WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Can you please help to convert it to Powershell?

Answer (score 1):

`Invoke-RestMethod` is supposed to be the appropriate PowerShell equivalent for `curl` command.

So, your existing curl command:

```
curl -k -s -u superadmin:password-X GET https://127.0.0.1/snapshots -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

can be converted to PowerShell like this:

```
$Header = @{"Authorization" = "Basic "+[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("superadmin:password"))}
Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Header $Header -ContentType "application/json" -uri "https://127.0.0.1/snapshots"
```

Comment: Hi Yash, Thank you for your response.

I get the following error:
Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Header $Header -ContentType "applicati ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Comment: It seems that you need to enforce TLS. Run this command & then try to run the above script: `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12`

Comment: use `curl.exe` and it works in powershell too...

Comment: Thank you Yash & Daniel. 
I tried with the option:
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
I still get the same error:
Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Header $Header -ContentType "applicati ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExc

Comment: OS is Windows Server 2019 Standard edition.
Poweshell Version : 5.1.17763.1971
I tried the following and get same error for both Invoke-RestMethod & Invoke-WebRequest.

$cred = Get-Credential
$Header = @{"Authorization" = "Basic "+[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("superadmin:password"))}

Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Header $Header -ContentType "application/json" -uri "https://127.0.0.1/snapshots" -Credential $cred
Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET -Header $Header -ContentType "application/json" -uri "https://127.0.0.1/snapshots" -Credential $cred

Comment: Get-ChildItem `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -Recurse | Get-ItemProperty -Name Version, Release -ErrorAction 0 | where { $_.PSChildName -match `^(?!S)\p{L}'} | select PSChildName, Version, Release | FL


PSChildName : Client
Version     : 4.8.03761
Release     : 528049

PSChildName : Full
Version     : 4.8.03761
Release     : 528049

PSChildName : Client
Version     : 4.0.0.0
Release     :

Comment: For now, I'm proceeding with saving the curl output (from batch processing) to a file and using that file in Powershell

Comment: Give it a go: `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls -bor
[Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11 -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12`, and then run the above script.

Comment: I tried that but it did not work